# Invisibility , Gone , visibility ROW & Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I use this code in Flutter and i want to Visible/Invisible some Row or column .
In android studio and java we use :

> msg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

but how can use Id for Row and widget in Flutter and invisible/visible widget and Row ?
this is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home : MyHomePage()
    );
  }

}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          //ROW 1
           children: [
             Container(
              color: Colors.lightGreen,
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
               child: FlutterLogo(
               size: 60.0,
               ),
             ),

             Container(
               color: Colors.orange,
               margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
               child: FlutterLogo(
                 size: 60.0,
               ),
             ),
            ],
          ),






        Row(
          //ROW 1
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
              child: FlutterLogo(
                size: 60.0,
              ),
            ),

            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
              child: FlutterLogo(
                size: 60.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),






      ]),

      bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
          color:  Colors.redAccent,
          height: 55.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: new BottomAppBar(
               color:  Colors.blueAccent,
               child: new Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.add , color: Colors.black),    onPressed: (){ print("helllo"); } ),
                   new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.remove , color: Colors.black),  onPressed: (){ print("helllo"); } ),
                 ],
               ),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}//MyHomePage
```

I want to use IconButton to visible/invisible two Rows.
how i can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special widget called **Visibility**. Keep in mind the inversion of state management which is used in Flutter. You invoke **setState()** and condition for visibility of the widget.
And don't forget to change your Widget to StatefulWidget

Refer to
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html

Usage:

```
child: Visibility(
visible: false,
),
```

Here is the sample which should work in your scenario, it hides the rows on Remove button clicked and shows on add:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WidgetState();
  }
}

class _WidgetState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool visible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(
          visible: visible,
          child: Row(
            //ROW 1
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: visible,
          child: Row(
            //ROW 1
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          height: 55.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: new BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("show");
                      setState(() {
                        visible = true;
                      });
                    }),
                new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.black),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("hide");
                      setState(() {
                        visible = false;
                      });
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: combine this with my example and visible/invisible with IconButton.

Answer (score 10):

You could use `Visibility` like this:

```
Visibility(
  visible: true,
  child: Text("Visible"),
),
Visibility(
  visible: false,
  maintainState: true,
  maintainAnimation: true,
  maintainSize: true,
  child: Text("Invisible"),
),
Visibility(
  visible: true,
  child: Text("Visible"),
),
Visibility(
  visible: false,
  child: Text("Gone"),
),
Visibility(
  visible: true,
  child: Text("Visible"),
),
```

And this would be the result:

```
Visible

Visible
Visible
```

Answer (score 3):

## Visible

#### Android (Kotlin)

```
linear_layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
```

#### Android (AndroidX)

```
linear_layout.isVisible = true
```

or

```
linear_layout.isInvisible = false
```

or

```
linear_layout.isGone = false
```

#### Flutter

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text(
      "Stack Overflow",
    ),
  ],
);
```

or

```
Visibility(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text(
        "Stack Overflow",
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

## Invisible (not visible but maintain space)

#### Android (Kotlin)

```
linear_layout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
```

#### Android (AndroidX)

```
linear_layout.isInvisible = true
```

#### Flutter

```
Visibility(
  maintainSize: true,
  visible: false,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text(
        "Stack Overflow",
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

or (when you know the size)

```
Container(
  height: 300,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text(
        "Stack Overflow",
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

## Gone

#### Android (Kotlin)

```
linear_layout.visibility = View.GONE
```

#### Android (AndroidX)

```
linear_layout.isGone = true
or
linear_layout.isVisible = false
```

#### Flutter

```
Visibility(
  visible: false,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Text(
        "Stack Overflow",
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home : MyHomePage()
    );
  }

}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _WidgetState();
  }
}
class _WidgetState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool visible = true;
  bool visible1 = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Visibility(
          visible: visible1,
          child: Row(
            //ROW 1
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: visible,
          child: Row(
            //ROW 1
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlutterLogo(
                  size: 60.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

      ]),
      bottomNavigationBar: new Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          height: 55.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: new BottomAppBar(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("show");
                      setState(() {
                        visible1 = true;
                      });
                    }),
                new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.black),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("hide");
                      setState(() {
                        visible1 = false;
                      });
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can wrap your widget with Visibility Widget like this and pass a flag true and false like this.**

```
   Visibility(
         visible: false,     
        child: Row(),  //pass your own widget here
```